# OperationContext.Current is getting null when enabling Workflow Persistence

Tags: c#, wcf, workflowservice, workflow-foundation-4.5

I am using WF 4.5 and Devart dotConnect(for persistence). I am hosting my WorkflowService in `net.Tcp` protocol using `WorkflowServiceHost`. I am sending some information in `IncomingMessageHeaders` of `OperationContext.Current`. It all works perfectly fine until I enable persistence. As soon as persistence is enabled the `OperationContext.Current` gets `null`. I dont know why this is happening and both the data in `OperationContext` and `Persistence` are necessary.
Here is my config

Behaviors.config:

```
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ParametersInHeaderBehaviour">
      <HeaderExtension />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="WorkflowService_Behavior">
      <!--<workflowServiceTrace />-->
      <!--<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />-->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="Custom" serviceAuthorizationManagerType="Capita.Prism.Authorization.Foundation.Managers.UserAuthorizationManager, Capita.Prism.Authorization.Foundation, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
        <authorizationPolicies>
          <add policyType="Authorization.Foundation.ADMappingPolicy, Authorization.Foundation, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
        </authorizationPolicies>
      </serviceAuthorization>
      <!--<oracleTracking connectionString="User Id=workflow;Password=oracle;Server=DEVDB;" profileName="Sample Tracking Profile"/>
      <oracleInstanceStore connectionString="User Id=workflow;Password=oracle;Server=DEVDB;" instanceEncodingOption="None" instanceCompletionAction="DeleteNothing" instanceLockedExceptionAction="NoRetry" hostLockRenewalPeriod="00:00:30" runnableInstancesDetectionPeriod="00:00:05"/>-->
      <workflowIdle timeToUnload="0"/>
      <workflowUnhandledException action="AbandonAndSuspend"/>
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Using this behavior `OperationContext.Current` is available but as soon as I uncomment `oracleTracking` and `oracleInstanceStore` the `OperationContext.Current` is set to null.

Please help!!!

Comment: Check this if it applies: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765072/appfabric-wf4-wcf-services-how-to-retrieve-current-url-in-codeactivity-without

Comment: Yess i am having the same problem and this will probably solve it. But i still don`t understand why this happens, anyway thanks a lot. You may post this as answer and i will be more than happy to mark it as the solution.